# How to convert a two column list to a matrix

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to convert two columns list into a matrix as shown in the attached image. The y-axis of the matrix contain unique items from first column of the list while the x-axis of the matrix contain unique items from second column of the list. The matrix is populated with number of occurrence of corresponding x-axis and y-axis item in the list. There are around 10,000 rows in the list.

[image: Excel screenshot]

I used this 'not-so-smart' way of doing this. First, I `CONCAT` the items from both the columns and then `COUNTED` their occurrence in the list. Then I used the Excel function to remove duplicates and pasted as a matrix. Next, I populated the matrix with `CONCAT` to uniquely identify the cells. Finally, I used `VLOOKUP` to find the values from the list. Is there a better and smarter way to accomplish the same? TIA

[image]

Comment: The standard way to do this would be with a pivot table, have you tried that or is there any reason it doesn't suit your needs?

Answer (score 4):

```
=LET(
x,B1:B11,
y,A1:A11,
ux,TOROW(UNIQUE(x)),
uy,UNIQUE(y),
HSTACK(VSTACK("",uy),
VSTACK(ux,MMULT(--(TOROW(y)=uy),--(x=ux)))))
```

Where MMULT is the actual calculation creating a 2D spill of the counts.
The VSTACK/HSTACK is just to build around the headers

Comment: Simpler solution with `MMULT()`. ^1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

Another Alternative Using `COUNTIFS()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=LET(α,A1:A11,
β,B1:B11,
φ,TOROW(SORT(UNIQUE(β))),
δ,UNIQUE(α),
VSTACK(HSTACK("",φ),
HSTACK(δ,COUNTIFS(α,δ,β,φ))))
```

---

Comment: Yes, dynamic formulas support both horizontal and vertical scalability. It works like pivot. I used this attribute for monthly pivot summery for one of my project. Good see same feature here.

Answer (score 2):

Pivot table will do this for you. You can achieve this using `Microsoft 365` dynamic formulas. Give a try to-

```
=LET(
x,SORT(UNIQUE(A1:A11)),
y,TOROW(SORT(UNIQUE(B1:B11))),
z,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(x),COLUMNS(y),
LAMBDA(r,c,
COUNTIFS(A1:A11,INDEX(x,r),B1:B11,INDEX(y,c)))),
VSTACK(HSTACK("",y),HSTACK(x,z)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `LAMBDA()` formula you can make it more verbose. So, you just need to specify input ranges and the formula take care other calculation inside `LAMBDA()`.

```
=LAMBDA(input1,input2,
LET(
x,SORT(UNIQUE(input1)),
y,TOROW(SORT(UNIQUE(input2))),
z,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(x),COLUMNS(y),
LAMBDA(r,c,
IFERROR(ROWS(FILTER(input1,(input1=INDEX(x,r))*(input2=INDEX(y,c)))),0)
)),
VSTACK(HSTACK("",y),HSTACK(x,z))))(A1:A11,B1:B11)
```

[image]